# Does the default queue (inline runner) for ActiveJob support delaying the execution of a job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

I am able to use the new rails 4.2 feature to deliver an email through ActiveJob

```
class InvitationModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    def send_invitation
        MyMailer.send_the_email(param1).deliver_later
    end
end
```

Will the default queue (inline runner?) support a specified delay, for example (pseudo code)

```
MyMailer.send_the_email(param1).deliver_in(minutes: 5)
```

Or do I need another gem for that?  By using ActiveJob with inline runner is the sending of this email truly async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The inline runner just runs the job. To be able to run jobs async you'll need to use a queueing backend. Only some of the backends supports scheduling jobs (run with a delay). See this table http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html